# Changing temporary file folder location in linux (for everything on the system)?

Tags: linux, redhat, temporary-directory

Currently its /tmp

How can I set it to /anythingelse so that all applications use that subsequently?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo rmdir /tmp && ln -s /some/other/loc /tmp
```

Alternatively, set the environment variable `TMPDIR` at the highest level possible. For the environment, or per user.

Comment: This does not change it from `/tmp`. This merely changes where `/tmp` points.

Comment: The clue is in "all applications subsequently". It doesn't get sweeter.

Comment: Changing `TMPDIR`, does change it from `/tmp`.

Comment: after doing that some apps didn't run: "cannot create temporary directory for the root file system: Permission denied"

Comment: You will probably need to create the directory in advance, and give everyone permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Specific applications may have configuration options or environment variables for this, but in general *nix systems are supposed to use `/tmp` for temporary files, and this cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you really insist, make `/tmp` be a symbolic link to whatever location you want (Matt Joiner's answer gives the specific command to do that).

For example, on Mac OS, `/tmp` is a symlink to `/private/tmp`. This arrangement can be used to facilitate the ability to NFS-mount `/` (presumably read-only) while keeping system-specific files that can't be shared (/etc, /tmp, and so forth) in a `/private` partition on a local disk.